# VSCode Material Theme conflict with built in TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features

Tags: typescript, material-design, visual-studio-code

Since a few days ago my Community Material Theme 1.4.1 -> Community Material Theme Palenight is conflicting with the TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features built-in VSCode extension. I am 100% sure it's from this because I tried disabling every other extension.

What I tried is to disable the built-in extension for TS/JS, and it goes back to normal.The theme used to have functions/methods colored with a light blue, but now they are a bright yellow.

I cannot use the editor without the built-in extension, but I cannot understand what changed these days to make this conflict.

This is how it looks like
[image]

This is how it used to look like
[image]

Steps:

1. Opening VSCode, everything looks fine
2. TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features built-in VSCode extension loads
3. Material Theme updates colors to yellow

Any help please?

Comment: Can you please add steps to reproduce this? What *exact* theme do you have installed?

Comment: Community Material Theme 1.4.1 -> Community Material Theme Palenight

Comment: Please edit relevant info into the question itself rather than in comments.

Comment: Thank you, added pictures too! I wasn't able to do this before ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved it

The latest version of VSCode ships with "semantic highlighting". Search your settings for the word semantic, and turn it off, and everything should go back to normal.